# Enterprise Architect java code generation enumeration

Tags: java, code-generation, enterprise-architect

using EA for creation domain model and I wonder if it is possible to specify enumeration class with properties and get those properly code generated to java code. Let say I have enum Times with property id. So far I was able to achieve following:

```
public enum Times {

OPEN,
CLOSE,
NONE
;

public int id;
}
```

My desired output should look as follows:

```
public enum Times {    
  OPEN(1),
  CLOSE(5),
  NONE(9)
  ;

  public int id;

  private Times(int id){
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Comment: In the model, do your enum values / attributes have initial values?

Comment: Yes, they do. The problem is how to define that this initial value for literal e.g. OPEN init value = 1 should be assigned to property id.

Answer (score -1):

You must add a tagged value to the enumerated values (OPEN, CLOSE, etc.) requiring the parameters (1, 2, etc.). This tagged value must have tag "arguments" and value consisting in a coma separated list of parameters. Go to the "Tagged Values" view of the corresponding enumeration attribute from the Enumeration Panel (double-click on the attribute->Properties->Tagged Values).
Have a look to http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/software_engineering/java_conventions.html for Java Conventions